# How to change the period after chapter label in the header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, books

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\normalsize\thepage}
 \fancyhead[RE]{\footnotesize\itshape Thesis}      
 \fancyhead[LO]{\textcolor{black!90}{\footnotesize\itshape\leftmark}}
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt} 
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\blindtext[10-600]
\section{Test section}
\blindtext[1-30]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See section 15 of the `fancyhdr` documentation for examples. Just take a fitting example and remove the dot after the chapter number (`\thechapter`):

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
 \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter\ #1}}{}}
```